# Java to C# conversion finding public fields of subclass with reflection

Tags: java, c#, reflection

I'm currently porting part of a framework over to C# from java.

I used the following line in Java to get the declared fields in order of declaration of the subclass of my abstract class. I would then use this field list to set the values via reflection.

```
Field[] fields = this.getClass().asSubclass(this.getClass()).getDeclaredFields();
```

I have tried using the following method to get the same result in C#. But this will return all of the public fields of the super class as well.

```
IEnumerable<FieldInfo> fields = this.GetType().GetFields().OrderBy(field => field.MetadataToken);
```

Is there some way i can achieve the same results in C# as the Java method.

To repeat myself, i ONLY need the declared fields of any subclass i make of the current class.

Comment: Maybe I've not had enough coffee yet, but how is "this.getClass().asSubclass(this.getClass())" different from "this.getClass()" ?

Comment: Haha, it probably is not. It was a while ago i wrote that. I was probably trying to ensure that it was the subclass only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to use [`BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Specifies that only members declared at the level of the supplied type's hierarchy should be considered. Inherited members are not considered.

For example, assuming you want private fields as well, and both instance and static fields - remove the flags you *don't* want:

```
var fields = GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | 
                                 BindingFlags.Public |
                                 BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                 BindingFlags.Static |
                                 BindingFlags.Instance)
                      .OrderBy(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`

Comment: Will this only get any Subclass' fields?

Comment: @LexWebb: This will not return fields declared by the superclass.